# PHP Unserialize Command array

Tags: php, arrays

I've encountered a weird problem with unserialize function. I can serialize an array but when I unserialize it I'm getting convert array into string error:

```
if ($i == 10) {
  $solvedarray = serialize($solvesarray);
  $solvedarray2 = unserialize($solvedarray);
  print "$solvedarray2";{
```

**Array to string conversion in /directoryofmyproject/ on line 29**

Any help ?

Comment: If I understand your problem (not sure which is line 29), you're trying to print the string. Try var_dump($solvedarray2);

Comment: Last character `{`??? close an if with `}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I suspect it's just a snippet, or that code would be giving a message along the lines of "unexpected end of file"

Comment: It's an array!  `print_r($solvedarray2);`

Comment: Thanks ! :) I've didn't noticed that print or echo function are automaticaly converting arrays into string :) Have nice day :) !

Comment: @KarlBuys I suspect you are right. My point is if the OP cannot take enough care to check 5 lines of code is accurate, what chance do we have of giving a good answer, or come to that why should we bother

Comment: @RiggsFolly Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help the problem was that I've wanted to print array using print function that is automatically converting array into string this solved the problem:

```
if ($i == 10) {
  $solvedarray = serialize($solvesarray);
  $solvedarray2 = unserialize($solvedarray);
  print_r($solvedarray2);
```